# If we divide a block per warps in CUDA/GPU, then all warps in a block used same shared memory

Tags: gpu, numba

If we divide a block per warps in CUDA/GPU, then all warps in a block used the same shared memory. Anyone give an example or explain how to write it by coding. like the below code is for the thread to determine its position in the grid and block. Now, How we can divide it as warp per block?

```
> @cuda.jit def my_kernel(io_array):
>     # Thread id in a 1D block
>     tx = cuda.threadIdx.x
>     # Block id in a 1D grid
>     ty = cuda.blockIdx.x
>     # Block width, i.e. number of threads per block
>     bw = cuda.blockDim.x
>     # Compute flattened index inside the array
>     pos = tx + ty * bw
>     if pos < io_array.size:  # Check array boundaries
>         io_array[pos] *= 2 # do the computation
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added the code as an example.